# Approximation function or equation

Tags: calculus, approximation

Is there any near approximation function or equation to this expression ?

$\ (1+e^ {x_0}) \cdot (1+e^{x_1}) \cdot... \cdot(1+e ^{x_n})$

thanks

Comment: Are your $x_i$ such that $|x_i|<\epsilon$ with small $\epsilon$ ? Then, by approximating each parenthesis by $2+x_i$, the result is $\approx 2^n+2\sum x_i$.

Comment: This depends heavily on the $x_i!$ If $|x_i|$ is small, you can use $1+e^{x_i}\approx 2+x_i,$ if $x_i$ is large you can omit the summand $1,$  and if $-x_i$ is large the term would be 1.

Comment: JeanMarie thanks

Comment: gammatester thanks